# Change active image react native

Tags: react-native

I wanna change the active image when it's pressed. So for example I have two zodiacs signs, Capricorn and taurus, and when the user click on Capricorn the image is rendered in color and if the user click on the taurus sign then the Capricorn sign will be in black and white and the taurus sign will be rendered in color. Actually I've only managed to change from black and white to color using states but it will always render the color image, I can't switch it on and off . Here is my code:

```
class Horoscope extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      belier:false,
      balance:false,
      cancer:false,
      capricorne:false,
      gemeaux:false,
      lion:false,
      poissons:false,
      sagittaire:false,
      scorpion:false,
      taureau:false,
      verseau:false,
      vierge:false,
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <View style = {{height: 150, backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginVertical: 8 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({belier: !this.state.belier})}}>
                <Image style = {styles.image} source={ this.state.belier === true ? require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-belier-100.png")
                  : require("../Images/gris/beliergris.png")}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {this.setState({taureau: !this.state.taureau})}}>
                <Image style = {styles.image} source={this.state.taureau === true ? require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-taureau-96.png")
                 : require("../Images/gris/taureaugris.png")}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
       </View>
)}
```

EDIT: I have also tried with a state `clicked` but still not know how to change his value to false when the user click on an other image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an Image mapper,

```
const Images = {
  taureau: {
    active: require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-taureau-96.png"),
    inactive: require("../Images/gris/taureaugris.png")
  },
  belier: {
    active: require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-belier-100.png"),
    inactive: require("../Images/gris/taureaugris.png")
  }
};

class Horoscope extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      belier:false,
      balance:false,
      cancer:false,
      capricorne:false,
      gemeaux:false,
      lion:false,
      poissons:false,
      sagittaire:false,
      scorpion:false,
      taureau:false,
      verseau:false,
      vierge:false,
    }
  }
  onPress = var => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      [var]: !this.state[var]
    }));
  }
  getImage = var => {
   const isActive = this.state[var];
   const { active, inactive } = Images[var];
   if(isActive) {
     return active;
   }
   return inactive;
  }
  render() {
    <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <View style = {{height: 150, backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginVertical: 8 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.onPress('belier') }}>
              <Image source={() => { this.getImage('belier') }}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is var in your code ?

Comment: `var` will be a dynamic variable. In the render function, it passes in `belier` to onPress. This will then perform logic on `this.state['belier']`.

Comment: I think I did it wrong cause I have an error message when I tried your part of code: 'expression expected' on the onPress and getImage. It's on the var

Comment: I also have this error : ''non-null assertions' can only be used in a .ts file.ts(8013)'.. What am I doing wrong ? I'm new to react native so I don't really now what's going on

Comment: I was dumb with the var thing. But your code doesn't show me the image. It says 'Invalid prop source' to Image. Do you know why ?

Comment: Ah, try `source={this.getImage('belier')}`

Comment: Indeed it's showing me the image but it's not doing the active or inactive. When I click on belier, it display me the active but if I click on taureau, it's not making belier inactive..

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to have what I wanted using `map()` but I have a problem with the layout now. I have 12 images to render but I can only show 6. And I want to have them 6 on top and 6 just below. Here is the code if someone need it :

And if someone knows why I can't display my 12 images I would appreciate. (will edit if I found it). Thanks

```
class Horoscope extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedIndex:0,
      selectedIndex2:0,
      belier:false,
      balance:false,
      cancer:false,
      capricorne:false,
      gemeaux:false,
      lion:false,
      poissons:false,
      sagittaire:false,
      scorpion:false,
      taureau:false,
      verseau:false,
      vierge:false,
      tabList:[
        {label:'1', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-belier-100.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/beliergris.png')},
        {label:'2', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-taureau-96.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/taureaugris.png')},
        {label:'3', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-gemeaux-96.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/gemeauxgris.png')},
        {label:'4', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-cancer-96.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/cancergris.png')},
        {label:'5', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-lion-96.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/liongris.png')},
        {label:'6', urlActive:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-vierge-96.png'), urlInactive:require('../Images/gris/viergegris.png')},
       {label:'7', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-balance-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/balancegris.png')},
        {label:'8', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-scorpion-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/scorpiongris.png')},
        {label:'9', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-sagittaire-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/sagittairegris.png')},
        {label:'10', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-verseau-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/verseaugris.png')},
        {label:'11', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-capricorne-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/capricornegris.png')},
        {label:'12', urlActive2:require('../Images/couleurs/icons8-poissons-96.png'), urlInactive2:require('../Images/gris/poissonsgris.png')}        
      ]
    }
  }

   render() {

    {console.log(this.state.selectedIndex)}

    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>


        <View style = {{height: 150, backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          {
            //loop throught the state
            this.state.tabList.map((item,index)=>{
              return(
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.setState({selectedIndex:index})}}>  
                    <Image
                      style = {styles.image}
                      source={this.state.selectedIndex==index ? item.urlActive:item.urlInactive}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>


              )
            })
          }
          </View>  
        </View>
   </View>
 )}
}
```

EDIT: Just using `flexWrap: 'wrap'`resolve it.